# Scrolling to top or bottom in left fixed div causing scrolling in right div

Tags: html, css

I've got a long "Table of Contents" in a left div which is fixed that needs to be scrollable because of its length. On the right is the content. Please [see it on JS Bin.](https://jsbin.com/zihuduh/edit?html,css,output) and make sure you make the viewport wide enough (>600px) to see the sidebar.

Here is the summary version:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="sidebar">
<div id="content">
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
#sidebar {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 175px;
  position: fixed;
  padding-left: 10px;
  height: 90%;
  overflow: auto;
}

#content {
    margin-left: 200px;
    width: inherit;
    padding: 1px 25px 25px 25px;
}
```

The problem is that when you reach the top or bottom of the left div by scrolling, the main content area will then start scrolling when you try scrolling up or down in the sidebar, which is weird.

I'm not sure if I need an entirely different approach to this problem or if I can get this one to work. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I don't think it is weird, actually I think it is pretty standard. I think that you should leave it as is as probably people is accustomed to this behaviour anyway.